# Undefined 'id' when i use Friendly_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm using the **friendly_id gem** for modifying my urls.
But i have a problem with my likes system.

For the use of friendly_id i change my **controller**:

```
@software = Software.find(params[:id])
```

to

```
@software = Software.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

So my **like.js** do not recognize the id of my model.
Here is the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
    1: $('#like-icon-software-<%= @software.id.to_s %>').
    2:   html('<%= j render "softwares/like_icon", {is_liked: @is_liked, software: @software} %>');
```

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english ..

**EDIT 1:**

I get in the params :

```
Processing by LikesController#create as JS Parameters: {"software_id"=>"Odoo"}
```

instead of

```
Processing by LikesController#create as JS Parameters: {"software_id"=>"1"}
```

without friendly_id.

**models/software.rb**

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

def is_liked user
    Like.find_by(user_id: user.id, software_id: id)
end
```

How to continue to receive the id and not the "slug" ?

Comment: What do you get in params for this action? Do you have `id` inside params? You can check it in logs

Comment: @Vasilisa Hi, i get in the params : Processing by LikesController#create as JS Parameters: {"software_id"=>"Odoo"} instead of {"software_id"=>"1"} without friendly_id. 
I edit my question with more info

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the 'title' of model 'software' in params software_id, as you have used it as a slug for friendly_id. `Software.friendly.find(params[:id])` brings record for the matching friendly_id. You will get the id as follows,

```
@software = Software.friendly.find(params[:id])
@software.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i do not understand how you want to implement your solution. Because i am already looking for the @software.id in the like.js

Answer (score 0):

In your **like.js** could you please use this:

```
$('#like-icon-software-<%= software.id.to_s %>')
```

instead of this:

```
$('#like-icon-software-<%= @software.id.to_s %>')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But that does not change the problem. My system of like works without friendly_id so the problem is that the slug is called in the params and not the id.